# How to integrate WebGL into existing game which is using canvas and 2D context.drawImage?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, rendering, game-engine

I have a game which uses `context.drawImage()` to draw spritesheets of the game objects into a hidden canvas which is then copied over to another canvas(viewport). The current renderer has a camera which copies a portion of the canvas to the view. Each gameobject is added to a layer in the renderer and sorted by some value x each frame before rendering. Layers are drawn in a specific order and objects in the layers aswell.

So I have following structure:

```
//Renderer object
var layers = [[object,object,object,object],//objects sorted according to when they should be rendered
              [object,object,object,object],
              [object,object,object]];

//Simplified one frame render function
for(var i = 0; i < layers.length;i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < layers[i].length;j++){
        this.drawImage(layers[i][j]);
    }
}

...
//DrawImage function
this.drawImage = function(object){
    if(typeof object.currentAnimation !== "undefined"){//draw animation
        var tileId = object.currentAnimation.tileIds[object.currentAnimation.currentTile];
        var amountOfBlocksInARow = object.currentAnimation.tilesheet.width/object.currentAnimation.tileSize;
            
        var sourceX = Math.floor(tileId % amountOfBlocksInARow) *object.currentAnimation.tileSize;
        var sourceY = Math.floor(tileId / amountOfBlocksInARow) *object.currentAnimation.tileSize;
        this.canvasContext.drawImage(object.currentAnimation.tilesheet, sourceX, sourceY, object.currentAnimation.tileSize, object.currentAnimation.tileSize, object.x, object.y,object.width,object.height);
        object.currentAnimation.nextFrame();
    }else{//if theres no animation just an image then draw with object properties}

}

...
//Rest of the render function
//snap camera to its target then copy the camera to the view
this.cameraSnapToTarget();
this.viewportContext.drawImage(this.canvas, this.camera.x, this.camera.y, this.camera.width, this.camera.height, 0, 0, this.viewportCanvas.width, this.viewportCanvas.height);
```

And this html: `<canvas id="hiddenCanvas"></canvas> <canvas id="viewportCanvas"></canvas>`

I was wondering if there was a way to implement the WebGL into this so I wouldn't have to change the structure. Currently I have tried to initialize webgl, make some buffers and shaders, but I can't seem to draw anything with it. I followed https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-drawimage.html this and don't know how to set up the buffers and shaders to benefit from the original code.
Do I have to change this structure or can it be implemented in this?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: There are are webgl implementations of the canvas 2d api. For example [this one](https://github.com/karellodewijk/canvas-webgl)

Comment: @gman Thanks for replying and the link, but I don't want to use any external library/api/code other than the WebGL for this project.

Comment: The original code sets up buffers and shaders so that's the issue?

Comment: @gman I have _some_ buffers and shaders set up, but I really have no clue what and how the WebGL draws a single image. I have images loaded before the engine starts up so I guess what I need is the implementation using those images and create textures, buffers and setting up the WebGL to draw them with above code. At the moment the images are members of each gameobject, but I could go with something that groups them in an array if it supports some kind of ordering for the drawing part. I have separate callbacks for updating the game variables and rendering the scene.

Comment: You need to make textures from the images (shown in the code) and pass the texture to drawImage. This would be much easier if you'd post a working **MINIMAL** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in the question. You can host images on imgur. Also did you read the linked articles from that article?

Comment: @gman Minimal snippet of the current code or the WebGL code? I don't have a working WebGL code tho. The above code is as minimal as I could get, there's lot more code in there and it wouldn't be working without a 500 lines or so.

Comment: minimal doesn't = post your game code. minimal = write new code that does something simple (draw and animate 2 images for example). Start with the simplest thing. Try to get that working. The code in the article works. We can't guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @gman I asked how would I set up the buffers and draw an image in this case. The code in the article does not cover it. It covers a case _x_, but not this one.

Comment: It implements `drawImage`. there are no other buffers or shaders needed than what's in the original code.

Comment: @gman Okay, for one there's used a "matrixLocation" variable which I could not find in any of the previous articles and it's not defined in the code. Hence it's not working on its own. Yes, I have the matrix math in a separate js file which is included, cleared all the errors which were produced by the article(for example the missing matrixLocation reference). Problem still remains.

Comment: It is defined in the code else they wouldn't run and the examples are all running live in the page. Make your window wider and the source appears beside each example. Click the "click here to open in a separate window" and view the source. Check out the source on github linked at the top of every page.

Comment: @gman I managed to get drawing working, will update the question with more code and information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There was a few things I needed to add for my code for this to work
First I needed to make textures of the spritesheets I use for the gameobjects:

```
//I load all my images into an array I can search from
var imageArray = [];//global variables
var textures = [];//global variables
//and use it after defining onload like this:
imageArray.push(img);
```

After images have all loaded I initialize the textures for the webgl:

```
for(var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++){
    initializeTexture(imageArray[i]);
}

function initializeTexture(img){//these images are already loaded into the dom
   var tex = renderer.viewportContext.createTexture();
   renderer.viewportContext.bindTexture(renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
            
   renderer.viewportContext.texParameteri(renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_2D, renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, renderer.viewportContext.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   renderer.viewportContext.texParameteri(renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_2D, renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, renderer.viewportContext.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   renderer.viewportContext.texParameteri(renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_2D, renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, renderer.viewportContext.LINEAR);
        
   var texture = {
       width: img.width,   
       height: img.height,
       texture: tex,
                    
   };
   renderer.viewportContext.bindTexture(renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
   renderer.viewportContext.texImage2D(renderer.viewportContext.TEXTURE_2D, 0, renderer.viewportContext.RGBA, renderer.viewportContext.RGBA, renderer.viewportContext.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
   textures.push(texture);//array containing one of each spritesheet texture
}
```

Then I have Animation object which I use to assign spritesheets to gameobjects:

```
function Animation(spritesheet,tileSize,tileIds,name = "",playOnce = false){
    this.name = name;
    this.spritesheet = spritesheet;
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
    this.tileIds = tileIds;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.currentTile = 0;
    this.playOnce = playOnce;
    this.texture;
    
    this.state = "stopped";
    
    this.setAnimationSpeed = function(speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    
    this.setTextureFromImage = function(img){
        this.texture = textures[imageArray.indexOf(img)];//find the spritesheet from array of images which is indexed same as textures array texture[i] = imageArray[i] etc. 
    }
    
    this.setName = function(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    this.setLoop = function (loop){
        this.loop = loop;
    }
    
    this.setSpritesheet = function (spritesheet){
        this.spritesheet = spritesheet;
    }
    
    this.setState = function(state){
        this.state = state;
    }
    
    this.getState = function(){
        return this.state;
    }
    
    this.play = function(){
        this.state = "playing";
    }
    
    this.stop = function(){
        this.state = "stopped";
    }
    
    this.nextFrame = function(){
        if(this.state == "playing"){
            if(typeof this.tileIds[this.currentTile+1] !== "undefined"){
                this.currentTile++;
            }else{
                if(this.playOnce)
                    this.setState("played");
                else
                    this.currentTile = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    this.setTextureFromImage(this.spritesheet);
}
```

As optimization I could use the index of imageArray and get the texture from the original texture array when rendering.
I use the Animation object in all gameobjects like this:

```
this.animations = [
    new Animation(this.spritesheet,32,[0,1],"walkDown"),//walkdown
    new Animation(this.spritesheet,32,[2,3],"walkRight"),//walkright
    new Animation(this.spritesheet,32,[4,5],"walkLeft"),//walkleft
    new Animation(this.spritesheet,32,[6,7],"walkUp"),//walkup
]
```

Finally I can render them with:

```
//Renderer
this.viewportContext = this.viewportCanvas.getContext("webgl",{ alpha: false ,premultipliedAlpha: false});
    
    
this.render = function(){//render one frame
    this.sortLayers();//can do sorting here
    this.viewportContext.viewport(0,0,this.viewportContext.canvas.width, 
    this.viewportContext.canvas.height);
    this.viewportContext.clear(this.viewportContext.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);//clear buffers before rendering
    for(var i = 0; i < this.layerArray.length;i++){
        if(this.layerArray[i].constructor === Array){
            for(var j = 0; j < this.layerArray[i].length;j++){
                var object = this.layerArray[i][j];
                if(typeof object.currentAnimation !== "undefined"){
                    var tileId = object.currentAnimation.tileIds[object.currentAnimation.currentTile];
                    var amountOfBlocksInARow = object.currentAnimation.spritesheet.width/object.currentAnimation.tileSize;
                    var sourceX = Math.floor(tileId % amountOfBlocksInARow) *object.currentAnimation.tileSize;
                    var sourceY = Math.floor(tileId / amountOfBlocksInARow) *object.currentAnimation.tileSize;
                    this.drawImage(object.currentAnimation.texture.texture,
                        object.currentAnimation.texture.width,
                        object.currentAnimation.texture.height, 
                        sourceX, sourceY, 
                        object.currentAnimation.tileSize, 
                        object.currentAnimation.tileSize, 
                        object.x,object.y,
                        object.width,object.height);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

this.drawImage = function(tex, texWidth, texHeight,srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight){
    if (dstX === undefined) {
        dstX = srcX;
        srcX = 0;
    }
    if (dstY === undefined) {
        dstY = srcY;
        srcY = 0;
    }
    if (srcWidth === undefined) {
        srcWidth = texWidth;
    }
    if (srcHeight === undefined) {
        srcHeight = texHeight;
    }
    if (dstWidth === undefined) {
        dstWidth = srcWidth;
        srcWidth = texWidth;
    }
    if (dstHeight === undefined) {
        dstHeight = srcHeight;
        srcHeight = texHeight;
    }
    
    this.viewportContext.enable(this.viewportContext.BLEND);
    this.viewportContext.blendFunc(this.viewportContext.SRC_ALPHA, this.viewportContext.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    this.viewportContext.bindTexture(this.viewportContext.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    
    this.viewportContext.useProgram(program);
    
    this.viewportContext.bindBuffer(this.viewportContext.ARRAY_BUFFER,positionBuffer);
    this.viewportContext.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
    this.viewportContext.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, this.viewportContext.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    this.viewportContext.bindBuffer(this.viewportContext.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordinateBuffer);
    this.viewportContext.enableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinateLocation);
    this.viewportContext.vertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinateLocation, 2, this.viewportContext.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
    this.matrix = m4.orthographic(0, this.viewportContext.canvas.width, this.viewportContext.canvas.height, 0, -1, 1);
    
    this.matrix = m4.translate(this.matrix,dstX,dstY,0);
    
    this.matrix = m4.scale(this.matrix, dstWidth, dstHeight, 1);
    
    this.viewportContext.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation,false,this.matrix);
    
    var textureMatrix = m4.scaling(1/ texWidth, 1/texHeight, 1);
    //scaling
    
    textureMatrix = m4.translate(textureMatrix, srcX, srcY, 0);
    textureMatrix = m4.scale(textureMatrix, srcWidth, srcHeight, 1);
    
    this.viewportContext.uniformMatrix4fv(textureMatrixLocation, false, textureMatrix);
    
    this.viewportContext.drawArrays(this.viewportContext.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```